# Push viewController on navigationController animated bottom to top iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

Is it possible to push a viewController on navigationController, which is animated, not horizontally but vertically [bottom to top]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I see that animation you describe I think people typically use a UIActionSheet or modal view controller to present the view.